# Is Good practice to use operations as method in mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I have have been using mongoose for a while. I wanted to know if I am doing it right or wrong and what will be the best practice.

What I am doing is::

/* myModel.js */

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

// 1. Created my schema

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
});
```

// 2. Want to use fetch operation
//  But I have created methods for that

```
mySchema.methods.fetchById = async function(){
  return await myModel.findById(this._id);
}
```

// 3. Created Model

```
module.exports = myModel = mongoose.model('myModel', mySchema);
```

/* myController.js */

```
const User = require('./myModel');

router.get('user/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let user = new User({
      _id: req.params.id
    })
    res.status(200).json(await user.fetchById());
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice to create an instance method in order to fetch an instance object because:

1. it is confusing, it can be error prone
2. it is against the *Mongoose* API design (see 1)
3. you have to create a new object, it requires more memory allocation
4. in this case it needs more line of codes, you need to learn a new API, you may introduce bugs and it doesn't add any improvements

You should simply use the static method `findById` in your controller:

```
const User = require('./myModel');

router.get('user/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).json(await User.findById(req.params.id));
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```